# How should one handle controversial answers which already sparked a discussion in the comments?

Tags: discussion, answers

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24998985/1139697) actually answers the question, it does so by ranting about function with no arguments first. That lead to a stream of comments, and a handful of downvotes. The fact that the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24998985/1) started with "Your brain has been broken" probably didn't help either.

Now one *could* remove the first two paragraphs, but this is, after all, his opinion. However it still gives the potential for some heated discussion.

So given an answer `A`, that contains some controversial opinion/statement `S`, which **already sparked a discussion**, should one simply remove `S` from `A`? Or should one vote to delete `A` alltogether? If one should simply remove `S`, how would one get rid of the now off-topic/obsolete discussion in the comments?

Note that in this case the question has already a second answer that is well-perceived.

Comment: No. Just because it's passionate doesn't warrant a deletion. If you disagree then downvote it: they're supposed to convey whether an answer is useful or not. If you're afraid of a heated discussion: *don't participate in it* and flag it if it crosses any boundaries.

Comment: If you *want* to participate and it is a civil discussion, then you can move it to chat. Though, you may not want a discussion with someone who helps by telling them that their "brain is broken"

Comment: This is a self-correcting problem.  See the downvotes on the answer?  Problum solved.

Comment: 1) take to twitter 2) invent ingenious hashtag 3) revel as internet takes revenge against answerer